# Removing nodes Graph dynamically from NetworkX is causing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Why this code is causing error?

```
temp=self.G.nodes(data="nodetype")
for nodes in temp:
    print(nodes)
    print(nodes[0])
    print(nodes[1])

    if nodes[1]==None:
        self.G.remove_node(nodes[0])
print(self.G.nodes(data="nodetype"))
```

**Error:**
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

I can solve the problem by using list but then i have to use 2 for loops. My graphs are big. it will be wastage of resources.
Here is what I am doing now.

```
temp=self.G.nodes(data="nodetype")
        for nodes in temp:
            print(nodes)
            print(nodes[0])
            print(nodes[1])

            if nodes[1]==None:
                blacksheeps.append(nodes[0])
        for nodes in blacksheeps:
            self.G.remove_node(nodes)
        print(self.G.nodes(data="nodetype"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, under the hood these nodes are within a dictionary, which simply does not support deletion during iteration. The standard workarounds are to create a list copy of keys/items to iterate, use two loops as you have above, or create a new object that excludes rather than deletes. If your graph is large relative to the number of items being removed, then what you have is best. If you expect to remove most items, then it would be better to create a new Graph that excludes what you no longer want.

Comment: This may be a silly question but I am not much expert in Python. but temp=self.G.nodes(data="nodetype") is not it assign values to new dict. so as per my understanding we are iterating temp. not graph.

Comment: You are iterating the dictionary that the graph uses to store the nodes, which is the [Graph._nodes](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/classes/graph.py) field. The Graph.nodes property returns a [NodeView](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/60d1d8af901c314533f8ac8d707a6c886f87a88b/networkx/classes/reportviews.py), that just wraps the original node dictionary. When you specify data="nodetype", this causes the NodeView to create a NodeDataView. If you look at  NodeDataView.__iter__(), you'll see that you're getting an iterator over the original node dictionary.

Comment: As the error says you are modifying the dictionary while iterating over it. One simple solution will be just push the node ids to a list and in the end when your loop ends you cann call **Graph.remove_nodes_from(nodes)**. This will remove the list of nodes in one go. Or just copy the dictionary :)